# Latex equation in github page

Tags: equations, subscripts, superscripts, mathjax

I want to write down [image: this equation] in Github page.

I have found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256433/how-to-show-math-equations-in-general-githubs-markdownnot-githubs-blog) and followed Quick and Simple Inline solution.

However, my question is not similar to the linked question because there is no link for superscript use. I want to know that how can I use superscript within Inline tag?

I wrote

```
p(x) = (2&pi;&sigma;<sup>2;)(<sup>-(1/2)) exp{-(1/2)((x- &mu;)<sup>2)/ &sigma;<sup>2}
```

after seeing this article but did not get result.

My equation looks like [image: that]

What should I do to create exact equation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think that this is really a LaTeX-question, so it is probably off-topic.
However, superscripts in HTML are indicated by `<sup></sup>`, so you can typeset your equation as `p(x)=(2&pi;&sigma;<sup>2</sup>)<sup>-&frac12;</sup> exp(<sup>-(x-&mu;)<sup>2</sup></sup>&frasl;<sub>2&sigma;<sup>2</sup></sub>)` or alternatively `p(x)=(2&pi;&sigma;<sup>2</sup>)<sup>-&frac12;</sup> exp(-&frac12;(x-&mu;)<sup>2</sup>/&sigma;<sup>2</sup>)`

Comment: this is off topic here as you can't run latex in a web page however you can use the mathjax javascript kibrary and use a latex syntax to get good math rendering, see the links in the mathjax tag I added under your question

Comment: @RenéB.Christensen Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the TeX program or one of the formats built on top of it.